# Python mock.patch.object for properties

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How a class property could be mocked? The mocked property doesn't work inside the class.

Code sample:

```
class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self._size = size

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size

    def volume(self):
        print(self.size)
        return self.size**3

def get_new_size():
    return 42


box = Box(13)
with mock.patch.object(Box, 'size', get_new_size):
    print(box.volume())
```

Returns:

```
<bound method Box.get_new_size of <__main__.Box object at 0x10a8b2cd0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in volume
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'instancemethod' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just patch it with a property:

```
with mock.patch.object(Box, 'size', property(get_new_size)):
    print(box.volume())
```

Note that you'll also need to make it so that `get_new_size` accepts an argument:

```
def get_new_size(self):
    return 42
```

Comment: You can also use a lambda: `with mock.patch.object(Box, 'size', property(lambda: 42)):`